# Convert a string of comma separated numbers into a 2D array

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string of numbers like so:

```
var original = "547,449,737,452,767,421,669,367,478,367,440,391,403,392,385,405,375,421,336,447";
```

And I wish to convert this string into a 2D array like so:

```
[[547, 449] [737, 452] [767, 421] [669, 367] [478, 367] [440, 391] [403, 392] [385, 405] [375, 421] [336, 447]]
```

But I'm having trouble doing it. I tried using regex:

```
var result = original.replace(/([-\d.]+),([-\d.]+),?/g, '[$1, $2] ').trim();
```

But the result was a **string** of the following and not an array:

```
[547, 449] [737, 452] [767, 421] [669, 367] [478, 367] [440, 391] [403, 392] [385, 405] [375, 421] [336, 447]
```

Comment: Is there a chance to have odd no. of numbers in the string. Ex: `1,2,3`? If it is the case what should be the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could look for digits with a comma in between, replace, add brakets and parse as JSON.

```js
var original = "547,449,737,452,767,421,669,367,478,367,440,391,403,392,385,405,375,421,336,447",
    array = JSON.parse('[' + original.replace(/\d+,\d+/g, '[$&]') + ']');

console.log(array);
```

Comment: Thanks Nina I think yours is the simplest solution. Many thanks for your efforts :)

Answer (score 3):

Might be easier to use a global regular expression to match two segments of digits, then split each match by comma and cast to number:

```js
var original = "547,449,737,452,767,421,669,367,478,367,440,391,403,392,385,405,375,421,336,447";

const arr = original
  .match(/\d+,\d+/g)
  .map(substr => substr.split(',').map(Number));
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `split` and `reduce` methods with `%` operator to create the desired result.

```js
var original = "547,449,737,452,767,421,669,367,478,367,440,391,403,392,385,405,375,421,336,447";
const result = original.split(',').reduce((r, e, i) => {
  if (i % 2 == 0) r.push([]);
  r[r.length - 1].push(e);
  return r;
}, [])

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be a nice use case for using `.matchAll()`:

```js
var original = "547,449,737,452,767,421,669,367,478,367,440,391,403,392,385,405,375,421,336,447";

var array = Array.from(original.matchAll(/(\d+),(\d+)/g), 
                       ([, ...m]) => m.map(Number));

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Regex and JSON.parse are costlier. Do it using array to matrix as below

```js
const original = "547,449,737,452,767,421,669,367,478,367,440,391,403,392,385,405,375,421,336,447";

const arrayToMatrix = (array, columns) => Array(Math.ceil(array.length / columns)).fill('').reduce((acc, cur, index) => {
  return [...acc, [...array].splice(index * columns, columns)]
}, []);

const result = arrayToMatrix(original.split(','),2);

console.log(result);
```